# What insect is this case from?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I found this insect case in my garden in the south of Melbourne (Australia), on concrete under some dried leaves of a tree that I'd cut down.

[image: insect case]

It is 8 cm long, which is pretty big for an insect! The photo is of the underside. I don't recognise it. What species is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be the [exuvia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exuviae) (i.e., molted) [pupa](https://australianbutterflies.com/pupa-chrysalis-cocoon/) of some sort of moth.

One Australian species with a similar-looking and sized pupa is the bardee or [rain moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trictena_atripalpis) (*Trictena atripalpis*; or *Abantiades atripalpis*):

[image]

<sup>Credit: [Dianne Clark](http://lepidoptera.butterflyhouse.com.au/logos/diannec.html) ; Source: [Coffs Harbour Butterfly House](http://lepidoptera.butterflyhouse.com.au/hepi/atripalpis.html)</sup>

See another similar looking (and coincidentally 8cm long) specimen [here](http://nationalparkodyssey.blogspot.com/2016/06/casuarina-camping-area-glen-rock-state.html):

[image]